# Absolute continuity wrt regular measure

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $\mu$ be a regular measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space i.e.
$\mu(U)=\sup\{\mu(K):K \ \textrm{is compact}, K\subseteq U\}$ where $U$ is any open set

$\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(O):O\ \textrm{is open}, O\supset A\}$ where $A$ is any measurable set

$\mu(K) < \infty$ where $K$ is compact

> My question : If a measure $\nu$ is absolute continuous wrt $\mu$ namely $\nu=0$ whenever $\mu=0$ and it takes finite values on compact sets, can I say $\nu$ is regular too?

I’m in the answer should be yes but I am not sure. How can I prove or disprove it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly you cannot say that $\nu (K) <\infty$ for all compact sets $K$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The measure is on a locally compact Hausdorff space. I’ve forgotten to indicate it I am sorry.

Comment: $\nu (E)=\int_{E \cap (0,\infty)} \frac  1 x dx$ gives a measure absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on the real line such that $\nu [0,1]=\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. So why can I say $\mu$ is regular since Lebesgue is regular on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384575/haar-measure-a-problem-from-folland

Comment: Maybe you want to take as an assumption that $\nu$ is finite, or at least that it is finite on compact sets.

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually I wanted to see why $\mu$ is regular on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384575/haar-measure-a-problem-from-folland and $\mu$ is finite on compact sets. How can I show inner and outer regularities?

Comment: @user519955: The situation there is much easier, since your measure is effectively living on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It is a standard fact / exercise that every locally finite Borel measure $\mu$ on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is inner and outer regular.  The basic idea is to let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of all Borel sets $A \subset U$ such that $\mu$ is inner and outer regular on $A$.  Show that $\mathcal{F}$ contains all the open sets and is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: This goes through more generally for any $\sigma$-finite locally finite measure on a Polish space.  Your original question is harder because it can include LCH spaces that are not second countable.  It might still have a positive answer but I don't know.

Comment: Does it hold for non-locally compact Polish spaces? Don't you need $\sigma$-compactness for inner regularity?